# How to add line after line to a numpy 2d array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to add line after line to a 2d array in python using numpy.

```
def read_file(file):
    # open and read file
    file = open(file, "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    # row and col count
    rows = len(lines)
    cols = len(lines[0]) - 1
    maze = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)
    for line in lines:
        maze = np.append(maze, line)
    return maze
```

First I read a file and get the lines from that one. Then I am creating a 2d array using the count of lines and columns (-1 because of '\n' at the end). Then I want to append them to the array, but it looks really weird:

```
['0' '0' '0' ...
'* * * ******* *** * * * * *** ******* * * ***** *** * ***** *** *\n'
'* *           *   *     *     *       *       *       *        B*\n'
'*****************************************************************\n']
['0' '0' '0' ...
'* * * ******* *** * * * * *** ******* * * ***** *** * ***** *** *\n'
'* *           *   *     *     *       *       *       *        B*\n'
'*****************************************************************\n']
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is the error?

Expected output is a 2d array (17,65).
Something like:
[[0,0,0,0,0...0,0], [0,0,0,0...,0,0]...]
etc.

I want to generate an array from this file:

```
*****************************************************************
*A  *         *         *     *                   *             *
*** * ***** * ******* *** *** * *************** * *********** * *
*   *     * *       *       * * *     *   *     *   *       * * *
* ******* * ******* ******* * * * ***** * * ******* * ***** *** *
*       * *   *           * * *   *   * * * *   *   * *   *     *
* ***** * *** *********** * * * *** * * * * * *** *** *** ***** *
* *   * *   *     *       * *   *   *   *   *   * *     *   *   *
*** * * *** ***** ******* ******* *** ******* * * *** * * *** ***
*   *     *   * *   *   *   *   * *   *     * * *   * * *   *   *
* ***** ***** * *** * * *** * * * ***** *** * * *** * * *** *** *
*   *   *     *   * * *   *   *   *     *   * *   * * *   *   * *
* * ***** ***** * * * *** * ******* ********* * * * ***** * * * *
* * *     *     * * * * * * *       *   *     * * * *     * * * *
* * * ******* *** * * * * *** ******* * * ***** *** * ***** *** *
* *           *   *     *     *       *       *       *        B*
*****************************************************************
```

every line is in brackets [] and after a new line a new bracket beginns.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: you want an array of 17 lines with 65 zeros? or you want 17 lines with the elements of each line padded with zeros? And how does your data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to have all the integers in a numpy array padded with zeros. This is how I would do this.

```
# open and read file
file = open(data, "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
# row and col count
rows = len(lines)
cols = len(lines[0]) - 1
maze = np.zeros((rows, cols),dtype=str)

for index,line in enumerate(lines):
    for i in range(0,len(line)-1):
        maze[index][i]= line[i]

return maze
```

this will produce this output:

```
[['*' '*' '*' ... '*' '*' '*']
 ['*' 'A' ' ' ... ' ' ' ' '*']
 ['*' '*' '*' ... '*' ' ' '*']
 ...
 ['*' ' ' '*' ... '*' ' ' '*']
 ['*' ' ' '*' ... ' ' 'B' '*']
 ['*' '*' '*' ... '*' '*' '']]
```